# Phone out of memory by loading data?

Tags: java, android, listview, out-of-memory, row

I have a ListView (MainActivity) with a few rows in it. Every row got an Image and a part of a text. All this data is loaded from an url/webpage. When you click a row, there opens a new screen (SecondActivity) with the full text. Everyting is loaded correctly and everything is visible. When you press the back button, open the second row in the Listview, press back, and click again on the first row, then the application doesn't load everything anymore.. It stops after 3/4 of the text. When I close the whole application, clean my RAM or use advanced task killer or something like that, open the app again, click on the first row, everything is loaded again, and the whole text the same as on the webpage is visible again.

Comment: Can you share some code and your logs? Will be hard to understand your problem just by this description. Also you should check the size of the image

Comment: @GhostDerfel The SecondActivity doesn't have any pictures or something.. And in my log there is nothing interesting stuff.. Cuz, the last line in my log is the last line on my SecondActivity/screen. So, the log doens't show the whole text too..

Comment: I already tried to put: NoHistory="true" in my manifest -> SecondActivity part. But doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So you don't really get any heap message?

Comment: @GhostDerfel No, the last line in my log is the same as on my screen. But, when I restart the application, and click a row for the first time this will shown in my log: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 900K, 18% free 29132K/35480K, paused 20ms, total 22ms.. 12%.. 11%.. till GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 50857K/55020K, paused 70ms, total 70ms.. (This shows up after when the MainActivty/Listview is loaded.. And before I click on any row..)

Comment: @GhostDerfel And sometimes between these "GC_FOR_ALLOC" logs I got a log with: Grow heap (frag case) to 35.945MB for 4000016-byte allocation.. Grow heap...... 39.758MB.....

Comment: Once I faced a similar problem and in my case the problem was with my picture loader, I was using pictures with 5MB when I only needed to show a fraction of the original size... I've solved my problem resizing the image after the download.

Comment: @GhostDerfel I understand, but when I scale my images.. So many times that I can see every pixel on the image.. Or when I go to my xml and set the ImageView visibility "gone" the text still doesn't load after a couple of times.. The same as before.. :-(

Comment: @GhostDerfel When I close my app and restart it.. It still doesn't load everything.. I must kill it, by clicking on my: Advanced task killer application.. After that it will load everything again.. (Only the first time if there is a big story/text on the SecondActivity.. If it is a small story, I can reload it for a few times before it doesn't show up anymore..)

Comment: Just to make sure your problem is in the images you are loading, can you test the app without loading the images? I'm not saying to set the visibility gone, don't load the images at all

Comment: @GhostDerfel I deleted everything with Image in the name in my MainActivity.. But my text still doesn't shows up completely in my SecondActivity.. I really think it is not in my Main but in my SecondActivity.. :-S

Comment: If that is the case, I don't think you have a heap problem... are you trying to load the hole bible twice in each activity? I don't think so

Comment: @GhostDerfel I don't know what it is, but it is weird that my log shows up that 18% 12% 8%.. I read also something about parse/parsing.. But I don't know how to do that.. Or if it is possible exactly how I want.. But I still have problems with my SecondActivity.. My MainActivity load everything correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use large heap for your App and put this line in your Manifest under Application tag.

android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Well I also get the problem almost same like that and it worked for me by increasing the heap size for my app.

Comment: I don't think the best solution will be to avoid to problem increasing the heap size...